# Как переместить блок flex

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Я хочу блок 'Инвестиции' `.post__section` переместить, чтобы он располагался правее даты. Я понимаю, как можно это сделать, добавив ещё `html` кода, но это будет лишним. Подскажите, как переместить блок, добавив только `сss`.

```css
.post__media__info {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.post__media__info div {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__date {
 min-width: 90px;
}

.post__tags {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__tags span {
 border: 1px solid #a3a4a6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post__media__info">
 <div class="post__date">19 ноя в 16:30</div>
 <div class="post__section">Инвестиции</div>
 <div class="post__tags">
  <span>IT</span>
  <span>Amazon</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убираем `flex-direction: column` добавляем `wrap` у родителя и у `.post_tags` добавляем `flex-basis` на всю ширину контейнера. в результате теги всегда будут на следующей строке!

```css
.post__media__info {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
  /*правка*/
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__media__info div {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__date {
 min-width: 90px;
}

.post__tags {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
  /*правка*/
  flex-basis: 100%;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__tags span {
 border: 1px solid #a3a4a6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post__media__info">
 <div class="post__date">19 ноя в 16:30</div>
 <div class="post__section">Инвестиции</div>
 <div class="post__tags">
  <span>IT</span>
  <span>Amazon</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
  <span>Big Data</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, прямо, кстати!

Comment: @МихаилКамахин рад помочь